# DOM Not Updating although function changes var

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Even though the variable value changes to a value that would cause the element not to render, the page does not update and the element remains rendered.

Tried moving inside component, did not work.

```
function clickHandler(item)
    {
    object[item].active = 0;
    }

let object = [{data: 
              <p onClick={() => clickHandler(0)}> Data </p>, 
              active:1},
              {data:
              <p onClick={() => clickHandler(1)}> Data2 </p>, 
              active:1}
             ];                                             


class Objects extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


render() {
   return (
    <div class="notifications">
    {object[0].active == 1 ? object[0].data : " "}
    {object[1].active == 1 ? object[1].data : " "}
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Objects />, document.querySelector('#object_display'));"
```

Expects to disappear but it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Changing external data isn't going to trigger an update of your component. You need to either change the props passed to the component or keep track of it in state inside the component itself.

Consider this:

```js
// data declared outside the component; gets passed as a prop
// in the ReactDOM.render call below.
const data = [
  {
    title: "Object 1"
  },
  {
    title: "Object 2"
  },
  {
    title: "Object 3"
  },  
]

class Objects extends React.Component {
  // initial state; start with the first item
  state = {index: 0}
  
  // onClick handler
  switch = () => {
    // get the current index out of this.state
    const {index} = this.state;

    // get the number of items in data so
    // we can loop back to 0 when we get to
    // the last item
    const {data: {length}} = this.props;

    // increment the index, don't go beyond length
    const newIndex = (index + 1) % length;

    // calling setState triggers a re-render
    // with the new index value
    this.setState({index: newIndex});
  }
  
  render () {
    const {data} = this.props;
    const {index} = this.state;
    const item = data[index];
    
    return (
      <div onClick={this.switch}>{item.title} (Click for next item)</div>
    );
  }
}

// data passed as a prop
ReactDOM.render(<Objects data={data} />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" />
```